# Very slow MySQL performance

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have 4 million rows in MySQL. I have a count query to fetch from DB to Apache web server.

The issue is first load (Count query) - when I click fetch button, it takes more than 5 mins.
Second time when I click fetch button in web app i takes less than 5 seconds.

I have added indexing and performance tuning(Removed WHERE, JOIN and many other tuning) has been implemented. Also Cache is also implemented.

Still it takes more time for first time.

Comment: Please show the query and the query plan (use EXPLAIN to get it) together with the table structure. Second time may be fast because of the query cache or other caches but first time has to actually count things. Do you really need exact count for entire table? It usually does not mean much because the table can be modified while it is running.

Comment: I have TTFB waiting time is 3 mins. 
When I did profiling in PhpmyAdmin.

What I should do to reduce this?

Comment: Is it okay to have this much delay from PHPmyAdmin?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. We don't know if it's ok or not, but we really need table definitions, sample data, the actual query and execution plan to be able to help.

Comment: Sorry I do not  have access to the DB but I have only the Front end info. And DB guys told that they have implemented the query optimization.